# Sort list containing string date

Tags: java, sorting, date, datetime

I want to sort a list containing a property date in string format:

```
 TestObj  test1 = new TestObj(
                ............,
                date:'SomeData, Friday, January 8, 2016',
                email:'user@mail.com');

 TestObj  test2 = new TestObj(
                ............,
                date:'SomeData, Friday, March 8, 2016',
                email:'user@mail.com');

list.add(test1);
list.add(test2);
```

I want to sort it using date field. Is it possible to use custom comparator and SimpleDateFormat to sort it on date field which is not in fixed format. Like month can have variable characters.

Comment: I would recommend storing the date as a date (a LocalDate if you use Java 8) instead of a string - sorting would then be straight forward.

Comment: @assylias I am getting it as JSON response.

Comment: Convert that json object to date object than sort

Answer (score 0):

Either implement Comparable in your TestObj or create a custom comparator and use Collections.sort

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the date from JSON, but you should parse the field, extract the date and convert it to a `LocalDate` when creating the object instances, probably in the constructor.

You *could* write a custom comparator but you would be doing an expensive conversion on each comparison operation during the sort.